# Proper way to notate a half measure rest in between sections

Tags: theory, notation, composition, time-signatures, rests

I'm working on a score in 4/4 and would like to insert a half-measure rest in between sections. What would be the most appropriate/readable way to do this?

Switch to 2/4 and back, like this:
[image: A measure of 4/4 (with four quarter notes), a measure of 2/4 (with a half rest), another measure of 4/4 (with four quarter notes)]

Or just add two beats to the measure, like this:
[image: An overfull measure of 4/4 (with four quarter notes and a half rest), a measure of 4/4 (with four quarter notes)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, both of them are readable by someone who knows notation, but the second one is technically wrong, since the bar is now 6/4 and not 4/4. So, you could either change the time signature to 6/4 in your second example (just for the first bar) or use the first example.

Comment: THanks for the answer! Yeah, that's what I thought too. I've seen the second one used though, but maybe it was a mistake.

Comment: The 2/4 bar is a better option, as it will be used as a break bar rather than the end of the previous part.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the first example, because the 2nd one is, as already answered, technically wrong. I would suggest a fermata-symbol after the last quarter note.

Comment: A fermata wouldn't work, as its duration is undetermined. There may be something else playing on those two beats which needs exactly a minimum timing. Although not so in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Why the fermata-symbol exactly? I wouldn't want any notes wavering into the rest, i.e. I prefer a hard stop.

Comment: Not a fermata, unless you want the last note prolonged.  If the exact duration of the break is important and the beat continues, write the 2/4 bar.  If you want a less determined 'breathing point' a caesura symbol ('tramlines') might be an alternative.

Comment: You can add a fermata to a break. dont know why you downvote my answer - so the player can play the break as long as he wishes.